# Kendo UI for Angular 2+ - combobox filter (display loaded information on init)

Tags: angular, filter, combobox, kendo-ui-angular2

﻿﻿I'm loading from database ﻿a record (Organization) which (could) have a parent (parent ID); when ﻿I'm displaying & editing the information (using the same form with Reactive forms) I'm using kendo-dropdown with filtering capabilities;  ﻿I'm loading its initial state (on ngOnInit). Though value is correctly set in combo, text does not appear.

component.html

```
<kendo-combobox
                    #orgParentId
                    formControlname="parentId"
                    [data]="organizationsLike"
                    [textField]="'name'"
                    [valueField]="'id'"
                    [filterable]="true"
                    (filterChange)="handleFilter($event)"
                    [placeholder]="'Search parent...'"
                    [suggest]="true"
                    [valuePrimitive]="true"
                    (selectionChange)="parentIdSelChanged($event)"
                >
           </kendo-combobox>
```

component.ts -> ngOnInit(): void

```
if (this.organization && this.organization.parentId) {
        this.organizationService.getOrganization(
            this.organization.parentId,
            r => this.organizationsLike = [r],
            null,
            () => {
                if (this.organizationsLike){
                    this.organizationForm.controls['parentId'].setValue(this.organizationsLike[0].id.toString());
                    // this.orgParentId.value = this.orgParentId.selected = this.organizationsLike[0].id;                         
                    // this.orgParentId.text = this.organizationsLike[0].name;
                    console.log('org like: ', this.orgParentId.text, this.orgParentId.value, this.organizationsLike[0].id, this.organizationForm.value);
                    // this.parentIdSelChanged(this.organizationsLike[0]);
                }
            }
        );
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a `ngModel` to your combobox

```
<kendo-combobox
    #orgParentId
    formControlname="parentId"
    [data]="organizationsLike"
    [textField]="'name'"
    [valueField]="'id'"
    [filterable]="true"
    (filterChange)="handleFilter($event)"
    [placeholder]="'Search parent...'"
    [suggest]="true"
    [valuePrimitive]="true"
    (selectionChange)="parentIdSelChanged($event)"
    [(ngModel)]="selectedOption">
</kendo-combobox>
```

And set the model to one of your combo box options

```
selectedOption = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.organizationsLike[0]));
```

[Demo - Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/RGbadSzyiOJgJtEtbD1b?p=preview)

**UPDATE:** Based on the comments,

If you are using reactive forms, you can just specify the initial value as the first parameter of the form control constructor.

**Example:**

```
public listItems: string[] = [ {name: "option1", id: 1}, {name: "option2", id: 2}, {name: "option3", id: 3} ];
public sampleFormGroup: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
     myComboBox: new FormControl(this.listItems[0]) 
                               // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ INITIAL VALUE
});
```

And whatever value you have specified there will be displayed in the combobox initially.

[Demo - Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/UXxjDHXGZOuUPTF2qs2Z?p=preview) (Using reactive forms)

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, but I'm using Reactive forms not template driven...

Comment: Many thanks!!!
To be honest I didn't do it as you said, but I've changed the way I define source:
export class OrganizationEditComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
....
   organizationsLike: Array<{ text: string, value: string }> = [];
....
}
The rest is the same...
I don't have an initial value, this value is set when reading information from database.
Thanks again for your effort and have splendid winter & holidays!